# Condition Statement printing in python

Tags: python, python-2.6

I want to print statements coditionally . The first function serves the purpose and gives me the desired output. I was wondering , if I could write the function is such a way that I do the condition check on both the stamenets rather than just one to get my desired results.

```
def display(A,B,C):
    print "--",'{0:^34}'.format(B),"--"
    if A:        
        print "--",'{0:^34}'.format(A),"--"
display('','My String','XYZ')
```

Desired Output:

```
--             My String              --

def display1(A,B,C):
    print "--",'{0:^34}'.format(B),"--"
    print "--",'{0:^34}'.format(A),"--"
display1('','My String','XYZ')
```

Output

```
--             My String              --
--                                    --


def display2(A,B,C):
    if A:
        print "--",'{0:^34}'.format(B),"--"
        print "--",'{0:^34}'.format(A),"--"
display2('','My String','XYZ')
```

Output :

```
Blank
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `C` as an argument?

Comment: well it is required to perform some other tasks , which are not required for this example. Well I now realize that I should have removed that before posting the query :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over `A` and `B`.

```
def display(A,B,C):
    for x in (A, B):
        if x:
            print "--",'{0:^34}'.format(x),"--"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start by clearly defining the behavior you want.   If you always want to print B, and only conditionally print A, then your first function is correct and trying to include both prints in a single condition does not match what you want.